# Possible to still produce iOS6 style apps using xCode 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, xcode5

for now I am keeping my app in iOS6 style until I get a chance to update some of the artwork. I am wondering, if I update to xCode 5, is there a way to compile my code so that it will still produce the iOS6 style and install it on my device with iOS7? Getting a bit tiring uploading my code through TestFlight...

Comment: No. Once you set the Base SDK to iOS 7 you get the new look and feel.

Comment: Be aware that iOS 7 and Xcode 5 are still under NDA, which restricts you from talking about them outside of the official Apple Developers forum. This might be why you will not get any answers for your question.

Comment: @rckoenes - Should I delete this you think?

Comment: @rckoenes Nothing being discussed here is under the NDA. No one is talking about features or APIs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not the Xcode version that provides the assets, its the iOS SDK.

That means apps which are compiled using iOS 6 SDK and lower will use the older style default assets, however apps which are compiled on iOS 7 SDK will use the new style controls.

Your best bet would be to create assets and style the controls to your specification if you want to use the new Xcode.

Comment: Using test flight I am able to install my iOS6 style app that I produced with xCode4 onto iOS7 and it still maintains the iOS6 components.

Comment: Thats probably a condition which wont last when you compile using the new iOS 7 SDK, which I assume is shipped with Xcode 5. There is no way to change that.

You also want to be careful as Apple will update their HIG and apps with the old style will start to get removed from the store.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: @StackOverFlowRider I changed my answer thats easier to understand.

Comment: So there is no switch in xCode5 that allows the developer to switch back to the iOS6 SDK?

Comment: You can copy an SDK (e.g. iPhoneOS6.1.sdk) from an older Xcode to

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs`
and it will appear in the build settings. But you might run into problems later with this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

No, Apple has changed the look of all system components. As far as I know, it is not possible to force your app to use the old style on iOS 7.

Comment: Using test flight I am able to install my iOS6 style app that I produced with xCode4 onto iOS7 and it still maintains the iOS6 components.

Comment: @StackOverFlowRider That's because your app has a Base SDK of iOS 6, not iOS 7.

Comment: Linking against iOS 7 SDK gives you the new components, and there is no way to force use of the old style. That's the bottom line.

Comment: @SevenBits - if you compile with xCode4 it will give you the old style on iOS7

Comment: You can still compile pre-iOS 7 apps with Xcode 5 if you link against iOS 6 sdk that can be simply copied from Xcode 4 to Xcode 5.

Answer (score 0):

You would get the new look on iOS 7 (when using iOS 7), When your app would run on iOS 6 it would look like it was on iOS 6.

It's pretty simple and straight forward. You don't have to do nothing just make sure it looks good on iOS 7 also.

To be more clear if you use AlertView you would get the new style when your app runs on 7 (with parallax etc.) and old look when run on 6.

My suggestion to you is just test it on iOS 7 and fine tune graphics if needed.

Comment: You can actually get the old style on iOS7 if you compile with xCode 4.

Comment: @StackOverFlowRider I don't think it's a good thing to do because most of the controls would be iOS 7 one (when running on iOS 7). Native controls are creating by the OS itself and not by the app.